# Elementary OS 5.1 flickering

Tags: release-hera, nvidia, spotify, vscode

I recently switched to elementary OS 5.1, in some applications like spotify and VS Code i am experiencing flickering of screen. Is there anybody who has experienced the same problems and how to solve this.
System setup: Dual boot along with windows 10
Graphic Card: Nvidia 1050 Ti

Comment: Which nvidia driver do you use?

Comment: First i was using 455 after that i switched to 450 but it's still happening